# What is the technical difference between a deformation and a perturbation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, deformation-theory, perturbation

What is the technical difference between a deformation and a perturbation? Do they exist in somewhat different categories?

Comment: I feel diffident saying this, since you've done plenty of work in which the word "deformation" is embedded (perhaps esp. in algebra where the name Gerstenhaber is also prominent), but these words appear in varying contexts. Is there a particular context in which you see both words being used, where a technical distinction would become important?

Comment: I meant it more in the sense of: what comes to mind e.g. context when one or the other of these appear

Comment: @JimStasheff I am very much interested to know about this ; did you ind out more in the last 3 years? Would you please share if there is any?

Comment: 'perturbation' can be thought in the context of stability/instability of wave propagation and hence mathematical.
Eg: In the field of Fluid mechanics, one could use the sentence "The perturbations of a liquid surface travel with visco-capillary speeds." Whereas, 'deformation' is more general.

Comment: I added "primary" tags but this can maybe be improved.

Comment: Sadly nothing significant. For myself, a perturbation could be just a small change while deformation brings to mind at least one parameter of change